# Google App Engine Python Search Api's Location-based queries (Geosearch) Issues

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-search-api, google-app-engine-python

I have implemented GAE's Python Search Api and am trying to query based on distance from given geopoint.

My query string is: "distance(location, geopoint(XXX, YYY)) < ZZZ". However, for some reason on the production server, this query string is returning items where the distance is greater than the ZZZ parameter.

Below are actual numbers (production) demonstrating the inaccuracies:

Actual Distance: 343.9m
Query Distance that still gets the result: 325m

Actual Distance: 18,950.3
Query Distance that still gets the result: 13,499m

Actual Distance: 55,979.0
Query Distance that still gets the result: 44,615m

Actual Distance: 559,443.6
Query Distance that still gets the result: 451,167m

Actual Distance: 53.4
Query Distance that still gets the result: 46m

Actual Distance: 35,322.2
Query Distance that still gets the result: 30,808m

Actual Distance: 190.2
Query Distance that still gets the result: 143m

On my development server, these inaccuracies do not exist. I am able to query down to the exact meter and get the expected results.

What could cause this and how to fix it so that I get accurate query results in production? Is anyone else getting the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

There can be two reasons for this :

1 - miles instead of km

2 - conversion numbers (for example 35,322.2 is 35322.2 ? km ? miles ?)
i suggest to check what exactly are the numbers processed when executing distance function, you can programmatically output this data in some logs

Hope it helps